# SQL Query to lookup data within last 24 hours while converting unix timestamp int value

Tags: sql-server

Hope all is well. I am looking to perform a query lookup against a specific date range (Last 24 hours) but when compiling my query, it provides an arithmetic error within what I believe is the WHERE clause

My example query is listed below:

```
DECLARE @nDays int = 1
DECLARE @timeVal int = dbo.GetUnixTime(DATEADD(day, -@nDays,GETUTCDATE()))
DECLARE @csTimeZone VARCHAR(256)

SELECT @csTimeZone = timeZone FROM APP_CommCell WHERE id = 2

SELECT @csTimeZone = TimeZoneStdName FROM SchedTimeZone
WHERE TimeZoneName = SUBSTRING(@csTimeZone, CHARINDEX(':', @csTimeZone, CHARINDEX(':', @csTimeZone, 0) + 1) + 1, 255)

SELECT clientname 'Client', Subclient, Instance, 
    dbo.UTCToLocalStringTime(dbo.GetDateTime(startdateunixsec),@csTimeZone) as 'Start Date',        
    dbo.UTCToLocalStringTime(dbo.GetDateTime(enddateunixsec),@csTimeZone) as 'End Date',
    jobid 'Last Job',
    backuplevel 'Type',
    jobstatus 'Last Job Status',
    jobfailedreason 'Failure Reason'
FROM CommCellBackupInfo
WHERE --ISNULL(startdateunixsec, '1/1/1970') > DATEADD(d, -1, @timeVal)
    idataagent = 'Virtual Server' 

ORDER BY startdateunixsec DESC
```

The column "startdateunixsec" is an int value. In my example the WHERE clause is commenting out the search for jobs within the last 24 hours. Is there a way I can get this to implement what I'm looking for, or will it require further adjusting what I have already compiled here?

Any recommendations would be helpful here

Comment: What exactly is the error and which line does it point to? Are your GetUnixTime and UTCToLocalStringTime functions broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more that one problem with your WHERE clause.

1. startdateunixsec is an integer, which is not compatible with the varchar value '1/1/1970'
2. you are trying to compare a number of seconds to a SQL Server datetime value
3. @timeVal is a number of seconds but you are using it as a number of days.

I think what you want is a WHERE clause like this:

```
WHERE @timeVal - ISNULL(startdateunixsec, 0) > 86400
```

Comment: That WHERE clause did the trick. Thanks for your help here! :-)